# OSGI Security with "BundleSignerCondition" not running on Equinox (trust keystore)

Tags: security, osgi, digital-signature, keystore, equinox

I have implemented conditional permission admin using "BundleLocationCondition" and it works fine. But now I also want to add signature condition to evaluate permissions. So I generated a local key and signed a test bundle with it. I also added the following entry in the policy file:

```
ALLOW {
   [ org.osgi.service.condpermadmin.BundleSignerCondition "CN=*, O=*, C=DE" ]
   ( java.security.AllPermission "*" "*")
} "Based on its signature give the bundle AllPermission"
```

Since the 'keystore' has password, I can not use "org.osgi.framework.trust.repositories" to tell the framework my certificate for verification. Using the information I got so far I started the framework by adding the following system properties:

```
System.setProperty(JAVA_SECURITY_POLICY, "conf/all.policy");
System.setProperty("osgi.framework.keystore", "file:\\C:\\Users\\..\\conf\\certificates.jks");
System.setProperty("osgi.signedcontent.support", "runtime");
```

And I have also added the following standard framework configuration property in launch configuration:

```
m.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SECURITY, "")
```

But the bundle is not getting the permission that it is given and it fails to access a package that it is importing.

Questions:

1. Is "osgi.framework.keystore" the right way to give the keystore location. And does it have an option to give it the keystore password like felix for example?
2. Is there any other system property that I need to set?
3. Is it possible to give a relative path of the keystore to the running project while assigning the value of "osgi.framework.keystore"?

Edit:
The steps I followed to create the keystore, certificate and sign the bundle are as follows:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore keys.ks -alias fortest -storepass testpass -keypass testpass -dname "CN=fortest,O=test,C=de"
keytool -selfcert -keystore keys.ks -alias fortest -storepass testpass -keypass testpass -dname "CN=fortest,O=test,C=de"
keytool -export -v -keystore keys.ks -alias fortest -file fortest.cert -storepass testpass -keypass testpass 
keytool -import -v -keystore certificates.ks -alias fortest-cert -file fortest.cert -storepass testpass -keypass testpass
```

And then I signed the bundle as:

```
jarsigner -keystore file:keys.ks -storepass keypass -keypass keypass bundle_to_be_signed.jar fortest
```

Then I only put the certificate in the running project directory (which is what I am trying to point to the OSGi framework as a trusted certificate to verify to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the version of the OSGI.

It might be a bug but the issue was solved when I change from,

**org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar**

to a recent distribution of Equinox,

**org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar**.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a password for the certificate. Simply create a new keystore and put your certificate there and leave out the private key oft course. Not sure if the way you registered your keystore is correct. You can use the default Java truststore though.
See http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/09/difference-between-truststore-vs-keyStore-Java-SSL.html

Comment: I have added an edit at the end of the question to show how I have created the certificate and signed the bundle(following the book "OSGi in Action". Do u mean I don't need to give password to "osgi.framework.keystore" property? Because it requires a password to create a keystore. How do u register a keystore, do you use osgi.framework.keystore or org.osgi.f?ramework.trust.repositories

Answer (score 0):

The standard keystore property is [Constants.FRAMEWORK_TRUST_REPOSITORIES](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_TRUST_REPOSITORIES).

You also need to set Constants.FRAMEWORK_SECURITY to [Constants.FRAMEWORK_SECURITY_OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SECURITY_OSGI).

Comment: I have set both of them but it doesn't work at all. And there is no option to create keystore without password so it is very disappointing why Equinox doesn't accept a keystore with password